# Búsqueda en BD por _id con express,node

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, mongodb, express, backend

Tengo dos colecciones dentro de una base de datos en MongoDB. Una es Libros y otra Autores, dentro de la colección Libros tengo: _id, titulo, tipo, nºpaginas, autores(el id de los autores almacenados en la colección autores) y isbn.

la idea es crear para el usuario una interfaz gráfica donde introduzca en un input el numero de isbn del libro y al pulsar el botón nos de la información total del libro, pero en el apartado autor aparezca en vez del numero de id de este, nos muestre su nombre.
el problema que me encuentro es que no puedo acceder a la colección autores. Si filtro por isbn y consigo entrar en libros y en el libro en concreto pero no coger el id del autor y buscarlo en la otra colección.

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

const mydb = "Ejercicio181";
const coleccion = "Libros"
const coleccionAu = "Autores"
const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";




app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db(mydb);
        dbo.collection(coleccion).find({}).toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send(result);
            db.close();
        });
    });



});

app.post('/verLibro', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    let autor;
    //Obtener datos del primer elemento dentro de una coleccion
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db(mydb);
        dbo.collection(coleccion).findOne({ isbn: req.body.libro }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            autor = result.autores;
            // console.log(autor)
            // console.log(result._id)

            // console.log(result[0])
            // res.send(`Titulo: ${result.titulo} <br> Tipo: ${result.tipo}<br> Nº de paginas: ${result.numeroPaginas}<br> Autores: ${result.autores}<br> ISBN: ${result.isbn}`);

        });
    })
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db(mydb);
        var obj_ids = ObjectId(autor).toString(); 
        dbo.collection(coleccionAu).find({ _id: obj_ids }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            
         });

        // dbo.collection(coleccionAu).find({ "_id": autor }, function (err, result) {
        //     if (err) throw err;
        //     // res.send(`Titulo: ${result.titulo} <br> Tipo: ${result.tipo}<br> Nº de paginas: ${result.numeroPaginas}<br> Autores: ${result.autores}<br> ISBN: ${result.isbn}`);

        //     console.log(result)
        // });
        db.close();
    });



});

app.listen(3000, console.log('Server in port 3000'));
```

```html
 <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Mostrar Libros"><br><br><br>
    </form>
    <form action="/verLibro" method="post">
        <label for="">ISBN:</label>
        <input type="text" name="libro" id="libro" placeholder="Introduce ISBN">
        <input type="submit" value="Ver inf de libro">
    </form>
```

Por cierto también tengo un botón que me enseña toda la colección de libros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No necesitas hacer `MongoClient.connect` dos veces si vas a realizar 2 cosnultas. Lo debes hacer dentro de la misma conexión. En cuanto pueda te muestro como hacerlo de forma correcta. Saludos

Comment: Tampoco necesitas hacer 2 consultas, puedes usar un `aggregate` con un `$lookup`

Comment: @MauricioContreras no lo consigo todo el rato me tira error incluso con async y await

Comment: @Pipe he leído algo pero lo que dices genera otra colección nueva con la fusión de ambas?

Comment: No, un proceso de agregación no "genera" una nueva colección a menos que se lo indiques explícitamente. Un proceso de Agregación es una forma de hacer consultas mucho más complejas que con simples queries no serían posible.

Comment: tengo que leer mas entonces, no me entero bien

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de la colección de libros? Me gustaría saber qué tipo de valor (o valores) tienes en el campo `autor` de los documentos de dicha colección.

Comment: @MauricioContreras lo subo a la pregunta principal

Comment: Lo ideal sería que autores no contenga strings, sino que sea un array de `ObjectId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea obtener la lista de autores de un libro basados en la búsqueda por `_id` en la colección de autores. Los valores de `_id` son parte del campo `autor` en el doicumento de la colección de libros.

Entre los muchos problemas que tienes en tu implementación es que estás tratando de hacer 2 conexiones diferentes para obtener la información. Y no sólo se trta de las 2 conexiones, sino que intentas usar variables que estarán disponibles únicamente dentro de su propio ámbito, porque no estás tomando en cuenta que todo petición a base de datos es asíncrona.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo primero que debes hacer es comprender que no necesitas abrir una conexión para consultar datos que se encuentran en la misma base de datos. Puedes hacer las 2 consultas usando la misma conexión. También debes entender que los procesos son asíncronos, por lo cual el manejo que harás de los mismos debe ser el adecuado.

Tu petición podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
// Dependencia requerida para hacer la conversión de string a ObjectId
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,


app.post('/verLibro', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  // Conexión a la Base de Datos
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      throw err;
    }
    const dbo = db.db(mydb);
    const query = { isbn: req.body.libro };
    dbo.collection(coleccion).findOne(query, function (err, libro) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);        
        throw err;
      }
      if (!libro) {
        console.log(`No existen libros para isbn: ${query.isbn}`);
        // podemos cerrara la conexión
        return db.close(() => {
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'No se encuentran libros'
            value: query.isbn
          });
        });
      }
      let { autores } = libro;
      if(!autores.length) {
        // el libro no tiene registrado ningún autor, no necesito consultar nada mas
        // cierro la conexión y devuelvo el resultado
        return db.close(() => {
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Libro encontrado',
            value: libro
          });
        });
      }
      // en este momento ya tengo la lista de autores, pero son strings
      // debemos convertirlos a ObjectId
      autores = autores.map(idStr => (new ObjectId(idStr));
      // ahora la lista de autores contiene objetos de tipo ObjectId

      // usando esta misma conexión buscamos los autores
      dbo.collection(coleccionAu).find({ _id: {$in: autores} }, function (err, autores) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          throw err;
        }
        // reemplazamos la lista de autores del libro por la obtenida de la DB
        libro.autores = autores;
        // podemos cerrar la conexión y enviar la respuesta
        return db.close(() => {
            return res.status(200).jason({
            message: 'Libro encontrado',
            value: libro
          });
        });
      }); // Fin de find()
    }); // Fin de findOne()
  }); // Fin de connect()
}); // Fin de app.post()
```

Como puedes observar, se hacen las dos consultas usando la misma conexión. Además se debe convertir la lista de autores de `string` a `ObjectId`. También puedes ver que he cambiado la lógica de las respuestas basado en si se obtienen resultados o no. Además estoy usando como respuesta una cadena en formato JSON y dejar así que sea el cliente el que se encargue de mostrar la información como mejor le parezca.

**Mejora usando `async / await`**

Como puedes observar del código anterior, al final he usado comentarios para saber qué función callback se estaba cerrando y no hacerme un lío. El problema de usar callbacks en métodos anidados es que puede conducir a errores y hace el código muy difícil de entender, porduciéndose lo que se conoce como [`Callback Hell`](http://callbackhell.com/).

Una forma de evitar esto es usando funciones tipo `async`. Los métodos `find`, `findOne` y `connect` del driver de MongoDB para NodeJS soportan el uso de `await`, devolviendo una Promesa cuando no se usa una función callback como último parámetro.
El código anterior podría verse así:

```js
// Dependencia requerida para hacer la conversión de string a ObjectId
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,

// la función callback que recibe el método post se declara async
app.post('/verLibro', urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
  // Al trabajar con Promesas debemos usar try catch
  try {
    const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    const dbo = db.db(mydb);
    const query = { isbn: req.body.libro };
    const libro = await dbo.collection(coleccion).findOne(query);
    if (!libro) {
      console.log(`No existen libros para isbn: ${query.isbn}`);
      // podemos cerrara la conexión
      await db.close();
      return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'No se encuentran libros'
        value: query.isbn
      });
    }
    // ahora buscamos los autores
    let autores = libro.autores.map(idStr => (new ObjectId(idStr)));
    if(!autores.length) {
      // el libro no tiene registrado ningún autor, no necesito consultar nada mas
      await db.close();
      return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Libro encontrado',
        value: libro
      });
    }
    // buscamos los autores en la colección de autores
    autores = await dbo.collection(coleccionAu).find({ _id: {$in: autores} });
    // reemplazamos el resultado en el libro
    libro.autores = autores;
    // devolvemos el resultado, cerrando antes la conexión
    await db.close();
    return res.status(200).jason({
      message: 'Libro encontrado',
      value: libro
    });
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
    // manejamos el error
  }
});
```

Este código es un poco más legible que el anterior, pero sigue teniendo un problema: realiza 2 consultas a la base de datos. Podemos obtener el mismo resultado en una sola consulta.

**Mejora con una sola consulta y `async / await`**

Para obtener los datos requeridos de una colección en la otra, podemos usar un [proceso de agregación](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/). En este proceso "agregaremos" datos de una colección (`autores`) en la consulta realizada a otra colección(`libros`). Esto quiere decir, que haciendo una única consulta la colección de libros, podré traer también información de la colección de autores.

Para lograrlo nos apoyaremos en las etapas [`$match`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), [`$lookup`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) y [`$addFields`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) y en los operadores [`$toObjectId`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) y [`$map`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/). Todo esto te ha de sonar familiar de acuerdo al proceso recientemente explicado. La idea es que la Base de Datos haga todas estas operaciones por nosotros y nos entregue el resultado listo.

Sin entrar en profundidad sobre como funciona un proceso de agregación, las etapas necesarias para lograr el resultado deseado son las siguiente:

```js
const pipeline = [
  // filtramos por isbn
  {
    $match: {
      isbn: req.body.isbn
    }
  },
  // convertimos los valores de cadena en ObjectId
  {
    $addFields: {
      autores: {
        $map: {
          input: '$autores',
          as: 'autor',
          in: {
            $toObjectId: '$$autor'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // buscamos la información en autores y la agregamos a los documentos encontrados
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: coleccionAu,
      localField: 'autores',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'autores'
    }
  }
]
```

Con esto, en una sola consulta de tipo `aggregate` obtenemos una lista con todos los libros que hagan match con el valor de `isbn`.

El código completo se podría ver así de sencillo:

```js
// la función callback que recibe el método post se declara async
app.post('/verLibro', urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
  // Al trabajar con Promesas debemos usar try catch
  try {
    const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    const dbo = db.db(mydb);
    const pipeline = [
      { $match: { isbn: req.body.isbn } },
      { $addFields: { autores: { $map: { input: '$autores', as: 'autor', in: { $toObjectId: '$$autor' } } } } },
      { $lookup: { from: coleccionAu, localField: 'autores', foreignField: '_id', as: 'autores' } }
    ];
    const libros = await dbo.collection(coleccion).aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
    if (!libros.length) {
      console.log(`No existen libros para isbn: ${query.isbn}`);
      // podemos cerrara la conexión
      await db.close();
      return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'No se encuentran libros'
        value: query.isbn
      });
    }
    // devolvemos el resultado, cerrando antes la conexión
    await db.close();
    return res.status(200).jason({
      message: 'Libros encontrados',
      value: libros
    });
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
    // manejamos el error
  }
});
```

Como se observa, el código es mucho más compacto y en una sola llamada a la Base de Datos puedo obtener el resultado.

Cabe destacar que un proceso de agregación siempre devolverá un Cursor de Agregación, por lo cual debemos usar el método [`toArray`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.5/classes/AggregationCursor.html#toArray) para obtener una Promesa que finalmente será resuelta con una lista de los resultados obtenidos.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Caballero me ha encantado su explicación eres muy didáctico y eso hace que quiera aprender cada vez mas, te lo agradezco. He probado el tercer código y me parece sublime voy a estudiar como la has realizado!. Ojalá consiga tener tu pericia algún dia!!!